# Server side migrated to FCM but client will use GCM with InstanceID.getToken() post April 11, 2019

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, client, firebase-cloud-messaging

As mentioned by Google, GCM will obsolete post April 11, 2019. But in migration page it is mentioned that if client is using InstanceID.getToken() then not need to make any changes.
Wanted to confirm that do I need to update client app post April 11, 2019, provided:

1. I have updated server side to point to FCM end points.
2. On app (client side) I am using the InstanceID.getToken() with GCMListenerService where receiver is "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" and Intet-fileter is "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIV".

The issue is that updating from GCM to FCM on client side is not an issue but releasing the app is huge task due to some other non-relevant factors so we will have to know if is it absolutely necessary to update the client side in this case.

Comment: t is clear based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) that GCM tokens retrieved via `GoogleCloudMessaging.register()` or `InstanceID.getToken()` will continue to work in FCM without any modification or renewal. I think there will be no casualties from the client side.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm as even FCM has the InstanceID.getToken() method so was not sure if new installation of client app with GCM library will continue to work and get the token post April 11, 2019. Can anybody confirm that?